# IOS phone launch screen mystery image

Tags: ios, iphone

When my app launches, the storyboard launch screen shows my image as expected but is partially covered by a gray box. Can someone give me an idea where the image box is coming from?

The only thing on the launch screen is an image that is centered on the page.

Here is screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Did you check if the launch images are corrupted?

Comment: Yes the Image is fine, in fact you can see it partially behind the gray box

Comment: Will you please post a screen shot?

Comment: screen shot added

Comment: That's awfully weird. The fact that the grey box isn't fully rectangular makes me think that maybe Badhan is correct and the image is corrupted somehow.

Comment: Can you download another image and use that to confirm that this is not image related ?

Comment: try this: Simulator > Reset content and settings

Comment: Badhan was correct I removed the image from the project and reloaded the original image and it works! Thanks. You should make this an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if the launch images are corrupted?